# Cross Compile C++ Qt Console Application from Mac OS to Windows

Tags: c++, windows, macos, qt, cross-compiling

I am building a C++ Qt console application using CGAL and Boost.
I would like this application to run in Mac OS and Windows.

I am searching to compile my application in Mac OS in order to create an .exe for Windows.

How can I do that ?

I found [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/40116/cross-compile-on-os-x-for-windows-and-linux) but it doesn't seems to work ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: May I know the reason you must cross compile? You can install Windows and dual-boot in on Mac machine or install it inside virtual machine and run from Mac.

Comment: I need my application to run in Mac OS and Windows and I would like to simplify the compilation and do everything on Mac OS with Qt Creator.

Comment: I used to build stuff for Windows, Linux and MacOS, the best way is to build natively on each target. Cross-compilation can't guarantee you optimized binaries and it introduces unnecessary hassle.